# The application failed too start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin ''windows"

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, exe, pyinstaller

Specs :

- Python version : 3.4.3
- Os :Virtual Box w/ Windows Xp Version 2002 Service Pack 3
- PyQt4 : GPL_win-4.12.3

Unfortunately the app needs to run on XP and I need to use a specific version of PyQT4 and python.

I build the executable with the following :
`pyinstaller --onefile app.py`

When I try to run it , I get the following :

```
The application failed too start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin 'windows'.
```

There have been multiple post with this same issue, they all recommend adding the .dlls along side the executable like so :

```
app.exe
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
/platforms/
 - qwindows.dll
 - qminimal.dll
```

These .dlls are from the **Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins** and **Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms** folders .

I've also tried adding Python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms to my environment path.

The issue still remains

Any ideas  ?

Comment: Qt5X.dll  for PyQt4???

Comment: @eyllanesc thats what shows up in the PyQt4 folder

Comment: Are you sure? Those dlls are from Qt5 but PyQt4 needs the Qt4 dlls that are incompatible versions. In your app.py script did you use PyQt4 or PyQt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc My app.py uses PyQt4 , and I installed PyQt4 with a binary installer.

Comment: mmm, execute in cmd: `set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS="1"`, then you run the .exe from the CMD: `/path/of/app.exe` and then you should get error information

Comment: @eyllanesc Done, but I don't see any error info other than what I detailed in my post

Comment: How have you installed PyQt4?

Comment: Yes I have using  a binary installer, I even used the designer tool to create and export my app.ui file. Which I then converted to an app.py that uses PyQt4. That all works fine, its just a matter of bundling it into an executable using pyinstaller.

Comment: Where did you download the binary installer?

Comment: @eyllanesc : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/

Comment: There are several .exe, which one did you choose? Also, is your PC 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204658/discussion-between-fabii-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: Instead of adding your answer as an edition of your question you should write it in the answers section and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the binary installer I was using contained .dlls for PyQT5. I found the correct binary installer with PyQt4 .dlls and now everything works as it should.